# Этимология слова «славянин»

Tags: этимология, заимствования

Исраэль Галицкий из Израиля мне задал вопрос: "*Slave* что означает?"

Речь зашла о славянах. Я говорю, что славяне никогда не были рабами, в отличие от иудеев. Он привёл пример написания "раб" по-английски — "slave", намекая на то, что, мол, от этого английского слова и произошло название "славянин", т. е. раб.
Поясните, пожалуйста, кто может.

Comment: Да. А вы не спрашивали его, отчего Брайтон-бич так называется? Там много бичей живёт что ли? Или одни погонщики скота с бичами собрались?

==============================

Это так называемая "народная этимология" (точнее, "ложная этимология"). И каждый "народ" норовит её под себя подстроить, доказать с её помощью, что другие "народы" похуже будут. Т.е. вам надо просто знать, что это толкование не научное, выдуманное от балды. А научное надо смотреть в этимологических словарях (например, Фасмера).

Comment: Начнём с того, что если эту версию и считать правдоподобной, то явно речь должна идти не об английском слове, а о его греческом или латинском предке. Продолжим тем, что более распространённым является точка зрения, что это слово "slave" происходит от слова "славяне", а не наоборот. Закончим тем, что эта версия не поддерживается большинством учёных.

Answer (score 5):

Единого мнения нет, а приведённая вами версия не является ни самой убедительной, ни самой популярной. Первые же ссылки по такому запросу дадут исчерпывающее количество версий. Например: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD

От *slovo=
Часто этимологию самоназвания связывают со словом слово. Таким образом, словѣне — люди, говорящие «словами» (то есть «по-нашему»). Сравнительно с этим название неславянского (то есть иноязычных племён) — нѣмьци «немые». Аналогичного происхождения самоназвание албанцев — shqiptarët («говорящие понятно»). Кроме того, в значении «народ» употреблялось слово ѩзыкъ («язык»).

От *slava
По другой версии, этимология самоназвания восходит к слава. Таким образом самоназвание «славяне» — это «славные», «знаменитые люди», то есть люди, о которых слышно, о которых говорит молва, о которых идет слава. Эта точка зрения, популярная в XVI—XIX веках, ныне фактически не имеет приверженцев среди лингвистов; общеславянской является именно огласовка с -о-, в то время как огласовка с -а- является результатом вторичного сближения со словом слава с XVI—XVII вв. и под некоторым влиянием греческого и латыни.

Answer (score 1):

Славяне - восходит к "слово" в значении "речь", точнее к общему морфу. Самоидентификация по языку - обычное дело не только для древних народов.

Вот что касается "славы" - это вряд ли. Во-первых нехарактерно, о славе начинают говорить уже потомки, во-вторых, само слово "слава" - к тому же слову слава и восходит. только более позднее.

"Славяне = рабы" - это чушь. Случайное фонетическое совпадение. Если посмотреть на родственные языки, "славяне" в большинстве случае пишется через "о", сохраняя древнее звучание этого слова.

А slave восходит к средне-греческому (византийскому) σκλάβος - невольник. 
Оно созвучно греческому именованию славян, но не более.
Подробнее, например, тут:
http://slavanthro.mybb3.ru/viewtopic.php?t=8776